# Postgres Extesions Not Available - CentOS 8

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos8

I have recently installed PostgreSQL 12 on My CentOS 8 Machine. It seems that there are not Extensions available, and when I try to create one I receive the following error:

```
[lloyd@localhost postgres]$ PATH=/home/lloyd/opt/GNAT/2019/bin:$PATH
[lloyd@localhost postgres]$ sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] password for lloyd: 
could not change directory to "/home/lloyd/gnatcoll-db-20.0/postgres": Permission denied
psql (12.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \dx
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(1 row)

postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory
postgres=#
```

Any help as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Lloyd

Comment: Could you check if you have a package like postgresql12-contrib or similar installed? Sometimes these are pulled out to packages like this.

Comment: Some languages(plpgsql, plpythonu, plperl, pltcl) are built in extensions that come with the core software. Other extensions(uuid-ossp for instance) are either in [contrib](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib.html) as  @g_bor pointed out or come from elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who stumbles across this issue, this is happening because you need to install the `contrib` package first, before gaining access to the `uuid-ossp` package.

First, ssh into your server and install `postgresql-contrib` by running the following:

**Note:** I had postgres12 installed and as a result installed `postgresql12-contrib` instead of `postgresql-contrib` because `postgresql-contrib` installs what looks like `postgresql10-contrib`.

```
sudo dnf install postgresql12-contrib
```

Be sure that this is the correct version of `contrib` for your version of postgresql. You can do so by making sure that the output of the install includes something like:

`postgresql<your-version>-contrib-X.X-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64.rpm`

Now, you should be able to add your extension!

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: this solution worked for me but I installed the required package with `yum` pkg manager instead `sudo yum install postgresql12-contrib`